# what is the best solution to split in chunk monthly given two dates startTime and EndTime in Java?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have to create algorithm to compute the chunk monthly given two dates.

example (format date: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) given two dates:

- startTime: : 2020-01-10 13:00:25
- endTime : 2020-03-19 15:00:30

I have to divide in chunk monthly the period above. 
In a nutshell if I compute the chunks would be :

- chunk_1 --> from: 2020-01-10 13:00:25  to: 2020-01-31 23:59:59
- chunk_2 --> from: 2020-02-01 00:00:00  to: 2020-02-29 23:59:59
- chunk_3 --> from: 2020-03-01 00:00:00  to: 2020-03-19 15:00:30

my first solution is the followed:

```
public static List<ExportDateSegment> datesBetweenWithCalendar(Date d1, Date d2) {

    List<ExportDateSegment> dateSegments = new ArrayList<ExportDateSegment>();
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(d1);

    int monthsDiff = mounthsDiffbetween(d1, d2);
    LOGGER.debug("months between two dates: {} ",monthsDiff);

    int i = 1;

    while (c1.getTimeInMillis() < d2.getTime()) {

        Calendar calendar;

        ExportDateSegment exportDateSegment = new ExportDateSegment();

        LOGGER.debug("last day of the month: " + c1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE) + " last hour of the month: "
                + c1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + " first day of the month: "
                + c1.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " month: " + (c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
        // the logic is to separate the three cases: the start period, intermediate period and the end period   

        if (i == 1) {

            calendar = new GregorianCalendar(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR), c1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    c1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE), 23, 59, 59);

            exportDateSegment.setStartDate(c1.getTime());
            exportDateSegment.setEndDate(calendar.getTime());

        } else if (i == monthsDiff) {

            calendar = new GregorianCalendar(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR), c1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    c1.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE), 00, 00, 00);

            exportDateSegment.setStartDate(calendar.getTime());
            exportDateSegment.setEndDate(d2);

        } else {

            Calendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR), c1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    c1.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE), 00, 00, 00);
            Calendar endCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR), c1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    c1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE), 23, 59, 59);

            exportDateSegment.setStartDate(startCalendar.getTime());
            exportDateSegment.setEndDate(endCalendar.getTime());
        }

        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        dateSegments.add(exportDateSegment);

        i = i + 1;

    }

    return dateSegments;
}


public static int mounthsDiffbetween(Date d1, Date d2) {

    int monthsDiff = 0;

    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    c1.setTime(d1);
    c2.setTime(d2);

    monthsDiff = (c2.get(Calendar.MONTH) - c1.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + 1;

    return monthsDiff;
}
```

ExportDateSegment is the bean that contains
startDate and endDate as attributes, in other words are the chunk.

Is there a smarter solution ?

Comment: Why use `23:59:59` as the end of segment? Wouldn't making it so that one segment starts at the point where the previous segment ended make more sense?

Comment: @Sweeper I have to use 23:59:59 because the segments are used to do requests to get data from signals with sampling interval to the second. If I use the segments chain as you are saying I would have a sample data repeated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Java 8 Time API, e.g. like this:

```
static List<TemporalRange<LocalDateTime>> chunkMonthly(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
    List<TemporalRange<LocalDateTime>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (LocalDateTime chunkEnd = end, chunkStart; ! chunkEnd.isBefore(start); chunkEnd = chunkStart.minusSeconds(1)) {
        chunkStart = chunkEnd.toLocalDate().withDayOfMonth(1).atStartOfDay();
        if (chunkStart.isBefore(start))
            chunkStart = start;
        list.add(new TemporalRange<>(chunkStart, chunkEnd));
    }
    Collections.reverse(list);
    return list;
}
```

```
class TemporalRange<T extends TemporalAccessor> {
    private final T start;
    private final T end;

    public TemporalRange(T start, T end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public T getStart() {
        return this.start;
    }

    public T getEnd() {
        return this.end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.start + " to " + this.end;
    }

    public String toString(DateTimeFormatter fmt) {
        return fmt.format(this.start) + " to " + fmt.format(this.end);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
List<TemporalRange<LocalDateTime>> list = chunkMonthly(
        LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-10 13:00:25", fmt),
        LocalDateTime.parse("2020-03-19 15:00:30", fmt));
list.forEach(r -> System.out.println(r.toString(fmt)));
```

*Output*

```
2020-01-10 13:00:25 to 2020-01-31 23:59:59
2020-02-01 00:00:00 to 2020-02-29 23:59:59
2020-03-01 00:00:00 to 2020-03-19 15:00:30
```

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use the `java.time` classes to do this. There are built in `TemporalAdjusters` that help you find the first and last day of a month.

```
public static List<ExportDateSegment> splitIntoMonths(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
    LocalDate segmentEndDate =
            start.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()).toLocalDate();
    LocalTime segmentEndTime = LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59);
    LocalDate lastSegmentStartDate = end.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).toLocalDate();
    LocalTime segmentStartTime = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0);

    if (lastSegmentStartDate.isBefore(segmentEndDate)) { // start & end are in the same month
        return Collections.singletonList(new ExportDateSegment(start, end));
    }

    ArrayList<ExportDateSegment> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // adds the first segment, which is not a whole month
    list.add(new ExportDateSegment(start, LocalDateTime.of(segmentEndDate, segmentEndTime)));

    // just like a typical for loop, but with LocalDate
    for (LocalDate segmentStartDate = segmentEndDate.plusDays(1) ; segmentStartDate.isBefore(lastSegmentStartDate) ; segmentStartDate = segmentStartDate.plusMonths(1)) {
        list.add(new ExportDateSegment(
                LocalDateTime.of(segmentStartDate, segmentStartTime),
                LocalDateTime.of(segmentStartDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()), segmentEndTime)
        ));
    }

    // adds the last segment, which is also not a whole month
    list.add(new ExportDateSegment(LocalDateTime.of(lastSegmentStartDate, segmentStartTime), end));
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Great minds think alike, though I decided to do it without adjusters. 

Comment: @Andreas Your solution is wayyy shorter! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one using streams:

```
public class SplitDateRange {

public static class Range {
    private final LocalDateTime start;
    private final LocalDateTime end;

    public Range(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Range{" + "start=" + start + ", end=" + end + '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-10T13:00:25", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-03-19T15:00:30", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);

    Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.isBefore(end), SplitDateRange::firstDateTimeOfNextMonth)
            .map(date -> new Range(date, min(end, firstDateTimeOfNextMonth(date).minusSeconds(1))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(System.out::println);

}

public static LocalDateTime firstDateTimeOfNextMonth(LocalDateTime current) {
    return current.plusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).with(LocalTime.MIN);
}

public static LocalDateTime min(LocalDateTime a, LocalDateTime b) {
    return a.isBefore(b) ? a : b;
}
```

}